# "Faites attention. Soyez prudent(s)"

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, synonymes

J'ai entendu une émission radio qui parlait de l'arrivée de la tempête Louis. En gros, le journaliste a évoqué le risque de violentes rafales et de fortes pluies. Il a terminé par : "Faites attention. Soyez prudents".

Pourquoi "attention" et "prudents" dans ce contexte ?

Quelle sera la différence avec la tournure "Faites attention. Soyez vigilants" ?

Comment: _Vigilant_: "garder les yeux ouverts" pour percevoir les dangers à temps (il y a _vigile_ dans _vigilant_). _Prudent_: mesurer ses actions avant de les exécuter. Quelque chose comme ça.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Faire attention** c'est être très attentif, avoir tout son esprit, sa concentration, tournés vers une préoccupation particulière.

**Attention** dans le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/attention), IA1 :

> I.− Tension de l'esprit vers un objet à l'exclusion de tout autre.
> A.− [La finalité dominante est l'exacte connaissance ou compréhension de l'obj.]
>
> 1. Application, concentration.

Comme synonymes de faire attention je donnerais, [être aux aguets](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/aguets), [être vigilant](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/vigilant).

**Vigilant**  dans le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vigilant) (A,2) :

> Qui porte une attention soutenue à certains faits ou évènements,
> notamment dans une situation tendue.

Être vigilant c'est donc être encore plus concentré, plus attentif, que quand on est juste attentif.

La **prudence** c'est le fait de prévoir, d'évaluer les conséquences de ce qui se passe. Être prudent c'est ne pas prendre de risques.

**Prudence** dans le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/prudence) (A,1,a) :

> Qualité, attitude d'esprit de celui qui prévoit, calcule les conséquences d'une situation, d'une action qui pourraient être fâcheuses ou dangereuses moralement ou matériellement, et qui règle sa conduite de façon à les éviter.

Si on me dit de faire attention et d'être prudent, je comprends que je dois rester très concentré sur ce qui se passe autour de moi de façon à évaluer correctement les risques que pourraient me faire prendre mes mouvements.

Si on me dit que je dois faire attention et être vigilant, je comprends qu'on attend de moi une même attitude mais à des degrés différents : « Faites attention, faites très très attention ».

On retrouve cette gradation de l'attention dans la [vigilance météo](https://vigilance.meteofrance.fr/fr) :

● Vert : Pas de vigilance particulière
● Jaune : Soyez attentif
● Orange : Soyez très vigilant
● Rouge : Une vigilance absolue s'impose

Answer (score 1):

S'il s'agit des ***s***:

L'*attention* de *faites attention* est un nom singulier.  C'est un expression figé, [faire attention](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/attention_1).

Soyez *prudent**s*** ou *vigilant**s***, c'est le deuxième personne pluriel (les annonces parlent à  tous, aux gens, pluriel), le pluriel au lieu de vouvoyer au singulier.  Ce dernier sans **s** est plus attendu surtout pour s'adresser à l'individu.  On voit les deux cas sur les placards, les affiches et à l'écrit selon le contexte.